# How to type EndpointDefinitions, so it accepts custom Args for params/body/id in RTK Query/Mutation

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have this implementation and it works:

```
export const reducerPath = 'api';
export const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: BASE_URL
});

export type QueryApiBuilderType = InjectedEndpointBuilder<typeof baseQuery, typeof reducerPath>;
export type InjectedEndpointBuilder<T extends BaseQueryFn, U extends string> = EndpointBuilder<T, never, U>;

export const createTransformedQueryEndpoint = <T, U = void>(build: QueryApiBuilderType, queryFetchArgs: FetchArgs) =>
  build.query<T, U>({
    query: () => queryFetchArgs,
    transformResponse: (response: { payload: T }) => response.payload
  });

export const createTransformedMutationEndpoint = <T, U>(build: QueryApiBuilderType, queryFetchArgs: FetchArgs) =>
  build.mutation<T, U>({
    query: (args) => ({
      body: args,
      ...queryFetchArgs
    }),
    transformResponse: (response: { payload: T }) => response.payload
  });

export interface IBaseItem {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

export interface IItemResponse extends IBaseItem {
  fullText: string;
}

export const itemsApi = (build: QueryApiBuilderType, url = '/item') => ({
  getItems: createTransformedQueryEndpoint<IItemResponse[]>(build, { url }),
  createItem: createTransformedMutationEndpoint<IItemResponse, IBaseItemResponse>(build, { url, method: 'POST' })
});

const baseApi = createApi({
  reducerPath,
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: BASE_URL
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({})
});

export const api = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    ...itemsApi(build)
  })
});

export const { useGetItemsQuery, useCreateItemMutation } = api;
```

Now I'm trying to add optional id (route param), params (search params), body (for mutation), but I lose the thread somewhere and can't match with the RTK typing system.

```
// modified createTransformedMutationEndpoint and createTransformedQueryEndpoint
 export const createTransformedQueryEndpoint = <T, U extends { id?: string | number; params?: object } = never>(
  build: QueryApiBuilderType,
  queryFetchArgs: FetchArgs
): EndpointDefinition<U, typeof baseQuery, string, T, typeof reducerPath> =>
  build.query<T, U>({
    query: ({ id, params, ...restQueryFetchArgs }) => ({
      url: `${queryFetchArgs.url}/${id}`,
      params,
      ...restQueryFetchArgs
    }),
    transformResponse: (response: { payload: T }) => response.payload
  });

export const createTransformedMutationEndpoint = <T, U extends { id?: string | number; params?: object } = never>(
  build: QueryApiBuilderType,
  queryFetchArgs: FetchArgs
): EndpointDefinition<U, typeof baseQuery, string, T, typeof reducerPath> =>
  build.mutation<T, U>({
    query: ({ id, params, ...restQueryFetchArgs }) => ({
      url: `${queryFetchArgs.url}/${id}`,
      params,
      body: restQueryFetchArgs,
      ...restQueryFetchArgs
    }),
    transformResponse: (response: { payload: T }) => response.payload
  });

export const itemsApi = (build: QueryApiBuilderType, url = '/item') => ({
  getItems: createTransformedQueryEndpoint<IItemResponse[]>(build, { url }),
  getItem: createTransformedQueryEndpoint<IItemResponse>(build, { url }), // added for id routeParam example
  createItem: createTransformedMutationEndpoint<IItemResponse, IBaseItem>(build, { url, method: 'POST' })
});

export const api = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    ...itemsApi(build) // ERROR 1
  })
});

export const { useGetItemsQuery, useGetItemQuery, useCreateItemMutation } = api; // ERROR 2
```

ERROR 1: Type '{ getItems: EndpointDefinition<never, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, string, IItemResponse[], "api">; getItem: EndpointDefinition<...>; createItem: EndpointDefinition<...>; }' is not assignable to type 'EndpointDefinitions'.
Property 'getItems' is incompatible with index signature.
Type 'EndpointDefinition<never, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, string, IItemResponse[], "api">' is not assignable to type 'EndpointDefinition<any, any, any, any, string>'.
Type 'EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<never, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, IItemResponse[]> & { ...; } & { ...; } & QueryExtraOptions<...>' is not assignable to type 'EndpointDefinition<any, any, any, any, string>'.
Type 'EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<never, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, IItemResponse[]> & { ...; } & { ...; } & QueryExtraOptions<...>' is not assignable to type 'EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<any, any, any> & { [resultType]?: any; [baseQuery]?: any; } & { extraOptions?: unknown; } & QueryExtraOptions<any, any, any, any, string>'.
Type 'EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<never, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, IItemResponse[]> & { ...; } & { ...; } & QueryExtraOptions<...>' is not assignable to type 'QueryExtraOptions<any, any, any, any, string>'.
Types of property 'providesTags' are incompatible.
Type 'ResultDescription<string, IItemResponse[], never, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ResultDescription<any, any, any, any, any> | undefined'.
Type 'GetResultDescriptionFn<string, IItemResponse[], never, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'ResultDescription<any, any, any, any, any> | undefined'.
Type 'GetResultDescriptionFn<string, IItemResponse[], never, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'GetResultDescriptionFn<any, any, any, any, any>'.
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
apiTypes.d.ts(29, 20): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

ERROR 2: Property 'useGetItemQuery' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, EndpointDefinitions, "api", never, unique symbol | unique symbol>'
/ Property 'useCreateItemMutation' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, EndpointDefinitions, "api", never, unique symbol | unique symbol>'. / Property 'useGetItemsQuery' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, EndpointDefinitions, "api", never, unique symbol | unique symbol>'.

Comment: What's stopping you from just writing them inline in `injectEndpoints`? None of these types is meant to be written out in userland, they should all be inferred.

Comment: I wanted to have reusable utility functions, so I don't have to write the same exact transformResponse for 100+ endpoints and fetch args with query/mutation args work easily, but once I changed url and params of the query/mutation it broke my types. RTK typing is quite overwhelming, I wish they offered more utility types to use, so we can make the process dry and reusable.

Comment: Another example where they provide 0 utility types for something like React Router v6 loader/action (from Data API): 
`const loadDeferred = <T>(queryEndpoint: QueryEndpoint<T>) => { const query = store.dispatch(queryEndpoint.initiate()); // try-catch defer({ dataAsync: query.unwrap()})}`
The QueryEndpoint type is my own and I spent hours thinking how to type it (working but I wish they had a  utility type):
`type QueryEndpoint<T> = ApiEndpointQuery<QueryDefinition<void, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, object, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, never, T, 'api'>, never>;`